# Is it possible to open Chrome both headless and maximized, using command line flags?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-prompt, shortcut-file

I'm attempting to configure a Windows shortcut to open a link in a headless, maximized Chrome browser window.

So far I've attempted:

```
..\chrome.exe --app=%s --start-maximized
```

as well as `--start-fullscreen`, `--fullscreen` and `--maximized`.

It appears that the usage of `--app` overrides and ignores any other flags related to window appearance, and I know of no other way to make Chrome headless.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have returned 3 years later with the knowledge that "headless" means that it runs as an invisible process (no GUI) and so the terms "headless" and "maximized" are meaningless together.
I believe I was looking for a way to launch an app in fullscreen mode. I still don't have the answer, but I hope this helps any internet travelers that come across this unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same problem as you and solved it via AHK script

```
^!z::
Run "chrome.exe" -app="https://example.com"
WinWait, ahk_exe chrome.exe
if WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
{
    WinActivate
    WinMaximize
}
Return
```

Like this hitting control+alt+z opens https://example.com in app modus and immediately maximizes it afterwards